# Avoid warning from Geotools StreamingRenderer: Rendering Buffer

Tags: java, geotools

In our application we get a warning from the method

```
org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.findRenderingBuffer(..)

  WARNUNG: Assuming rendering buffer = 0, but estimation is not 
  accurate, you may want to set a buffer manually.
```

The message appears when a layer containing lots of polygons is drawn at a very small scale. The style of the polygons defines an extra stroke for their outlines.

**EDIT**: This happens when using Stroke.NULL for the outline of polygons. It does not happen, when an individual stroke is set.

What is the reason for this message and how can it be avoided?

Thank you

Comment: can you add a short SLD that generates this - I'll file a bug if I can reproduce it

Comment: @iant I already filed a [bug report](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GEOT-4478). The SLD will be attached soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This occurs when the [buffer](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/master/modules/library/render/src/main/java/org/geotools/renderer/lite/MetaBufferEstimator.java) that needs to be added to the rendering area can't be calculated exactly - There are a few places where `estimateAccurate` is set to false (which triggers that warning) - something to do with the width of the stroke or the size of a graphic usually.

So you may have an SLD problem.

Comment: Thanks. The problem seems to bee Stroke.NULL, see my edit above. Checking the code of MetaBufferEstimator shows that it doesn't takle care for Stroke.NULL where most expressions are ConstantExpression.NULL.